# Android system date reset to today

Tags: android, date, settings

I want to test some of my app feature at a future date. So change my phone date on 20 March 2017 but after 10-15 second system automatically reset back to today. I turned off both switch for Automatic date and time AND automatic time zone.

I also tried after restarting device but the same result.

I also tried Moto g, G turbo Nexus 4 and 5.

Anyone can help on this.

Comment: some app on your device may auto-sync time with the network. It is really non-programming related question, but your specific firmware/device/apps installed question. Try using different device or emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please turn off the network connection. I also had the same problem . some system service will automatically sync time when network is available

Thanks

Comment: I turned off both switch for Automatic date and time AND automatic time zone.

Comment: Okay but you have to turn off wifi and mobile data also

Comment: If I turn of data/wifi then how I test my app.

Comment: then turn off the play services. then you didnt get the notification , gcm or fcm